# Почему у меня не работает password_verify?

Tags: php, password-hash

Почему код выдает **false**?

```php
$myPWD = 'mySecretPwd123';
$hash = password_hash($myPWD, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
var_dump($hash);

$verifyPwd = password_verify($password, $hash);
var_dump($verifyPwd);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: __Возвращает TRUE или FALSE, в зависимости от результатов проверки.__

Answer (score 3):

У вас стоит не объявленная переменная `$password`. Попробуйте

```
$verifyPwd = password_verify($myPWD, $hash);
var_dump($verifyPwd);
```

Comment: тю, просто сразу задавал $password, а потом забыл поменять. но тогда не работа, а сейчас нормально все, ладно спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста!) Поверьте опыту, ещё будет много ошибок типа "забыл", "не заметил" и т.д.)))